# Permutações e ficheiros

Tags: python, arquivo, python-2.7

Estou a trabalhar numa brincadeira que envolve permutações, para criar uma lista de palavras, em vários ficheiros à parte. Os problemas começam a surgir quando requisito palavras com mais de 4 letras, pois o ficheiro correspondente fica muito pesado. O que eu queria é que cada vez que um dado ficheiro chegasse às 499 999 (por exemplo) que abri-se outro ficheiro com o mesmo nome mas com uma extensão. Por exemplo palavras de 4 caracteres "`wl4_1.txt`, `wl4_2.txt` ..." onde o "`wl4_2.txt`" é a continuação do "`wl4_1.txt`", e a primeira linha deste ("`wl4_2.txt`") seria a linha de número 500 000 do "`wl4_1.txt`", ou seja, fecharíamos o "`wl4_1.txt`" e continuaríamos a nossa lista no "`wl4_2.txt`".

Este código em baixo funciona lindamente, só lhe queria adicionar essa funcionalidade que expliquei. Neste exemplo são palavras de 3 letras e já é pesado (830 584 linhas):

```python
import itertools
import string

def main():

    alphabet = string.letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    alphaLen = len(alphabet)

    print alphabet
    for i in range(3):
        NumToPerm = i+1 #remove 0 from the permutations function
        fileTest = open("word_lists/wl" +str(NumToPerm)+ ".txt", "w")

        perm(fileTest, alphabet, NumToPerm)

def perm(fileTest, alphabet, NumToPerm):

        for p in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=NumToPerm):

            word = str(p)

            for char in word:
               if char in " (),'":
                  word = word.replace(char,'')

            fileTest.write(word+ '\n')

        fileTest.close()

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, você não precisa chamar `perm` de dentro de `get_file_extn`: apenas retorne para função chamadora! Se você chamar `perm` de lá, você estará iniciando do zero, o que não é o que você quer (e sim continuar de onde está).

Apenas lembre de retornar o novo `fileTest`, pois o anterior foi fechado (se você tentasse utilizá-lo, daria erro). E não o feche duas vezes!

```
def get_file_extn(fileTest, alphabet, NumToPerm, countExtn):
    #fileTest.close()
    fileTest = open("word_lists/wl" +str(NumToPerm)+ "_" +str(countExtn)+ ".txt", "w")
    return fileTest

def perm(fileTest, alphabet, NumToPerm):
    ...
    if countWords == 999:
        fileTest.close()
        fileTest = get_file_extn(fileTest, alphabet, NumToPerm, countExtn)
        countExtn = countExtn + 1
```

Em segundo lugar, o `countWords` chegou em `999`, mas se você não o resetar para zero, ele vai passar pro `1000` e continuar crescendo - sem nunca entrar no `if` de novo! Como a próxima linha já vai aumentá-lo em `1`, atribua-o a zero no final do `if`:

```
    if countWords == 999:
        fileTest.close()
        get_file_extn(fileTest, alphabet, NumToPerm, countExtn)
        countExtn = countExtn + 1
        countWords = 0

    countWords = countWords + 1
    ...
```

Terceiro, você está atribuindo `countExtn` para `1` dentro do laço `for`. Para toda palavra lida, ele vai ser `1`! Em vez disso, atribua-o antes do `for`:

```
    countExtn = 1
    for p in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=NumToPerm):
```

Com isso você consegue a separação em arquivos. Um último detalhe: o primeiro arquivo aberto, no `main`, não usou sua convenção `wl_X_Y.txt`, mas simplesmente `wl_X.txt`. E ele vai receber as primeiras `999` palavras, enquanto o `wl_X_1.txt` vai receber da milésima em diante. Seria preferível que a `main` criasse o arquivo 1, e o `perm` já iniciasse `countExtn` com `2` (pois o 1 já foi criado):

```
def main():
    ...
    fileTest = open("word_lists/wl" +str(NumToPerm)+ "_1.txt", "w")

    perm(fileTest, alphabet, NumToPerm)  

def perm(fileTest, alphabet, NumToPerm):
    ...
    countExtn = 2
    for p in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=NumToPerm):
```

Comment: Obgado, mas algo se passa, esta-me a dar erro relativo ao ficheiro. Editei o código em cima, na tentativa e pus o que percebi que você me disse

Comment: @Miguel Que erro que está dando? Pela sua edição, vi que só corrigiu *parte* dos problemas, vários deles mencionados na resposta ainda estão lá (por exemplo, você está retornando `fileTest` da sua função, mas não está usando o retorno, por isso quando você tenta escrever na *stream* já fechada ele deve acusar um erro. É isso que está acontecendo?).

Comment: Sim é isso. ("...fileTest.write(word+ '\n')
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file"). Como implemento o retorno neste caso?

Answer (score 0):

A proposta que apresento altera um pouco a abordagem de pergunta:

- Simplificar a script para passar apenas a gerar as permutações do comprimento recebido via linha de comando, enviando para a `stdout`.
- O sistema operativo faz a divisão em ficheiros 
  (comando `split`).

ou seja:

```
import itertools
import string
import sys

def main():
    alphabet = string.letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    perm(alphabet, int(sys.argv[1]))

def perm(alphabet, NumToPerm):
    for p in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=NumToPerm):
        print  "".join(p)

main()
```

Modo de utilização:

```
python x.py 3 | split -d --additional-suffix=.txt  -l 50000 - wl
```